# trouble installing an npm package

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to install `react-navigation` in a react-native app I'm working on and I keep getting this error....

```
Standard error:
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: C:\John\Applications\cygwin\bin\git.EXE clone -q git://github.com/react-navigation/react-native-tab-view.git C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-e11f65d1 --config core.longpaths=true
npm ERR! fatal: Invalid path '/cygdrive/c/Users/John/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache/_cacache/tmp/C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-e11f65d1': No such file or directory
npm ERR!
```

I have no problem with other packages, and I have git and it works. I have npm and it works.

So far I've manually deleted cpm cache from `C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm_cache`. Ran `npm i -g npm` Deleted `package-lock.json`

But nothing is working. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to see what the NPM debug.log in npm-cache is saying. One example I came across was that the error code 128 can occur when you're installing a package that has a private repo as a dependency. Try to see if that is the issue. Because if the package depends on a private repo, it can't download that private repo and will throw an error similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For my case at least I have git installed via cygwin and have cygwin in my path. I guess for some reason this package doesn't like that?

But I uninstalled git from cygwin and then installed it the 'normal' way and then it worked.